# Null Reference Exception with System.Reflection.Assembly

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have developed a Library for internal email reporting. When I am using that Library from another project (By Adding Reference).

It gives `NullReferenceException` on the following line.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

Any idea, why Assembly is null?

Comment: Does this apply? From [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx): The GetEntryAssembly method can return Nothing when a managed assembly has been loaded from an unmanaged application.

Comment: Unmanaged code? Both Applications are developed in same version of .net

Comment: @Ani, I think its managed, because both applications are developed in .net 3.5 and both are under same source control.

Comment: I had the same issue when I run unit test through Resharper Unit Test GUI.

Comment: @Jenea, had you found any solution for it thn?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't look for it. So I would be also interested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is solved guys,

I am using

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.UnderlyingSystemType).GetName().Name
```

to get the EntryAssemblyName.
In this case I already has parameter which is taking Exception 'ex', so I solved it by using that.

Many Thanks Guys, specially @Aliostad

Cheers

Comment: Aliostad already answered this.  It's not a good practice to make a program blow up  in order to get a result.  You can simple Follow Aliostad's cleaner approach by simply : System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name

Comment: @Scorpion is there any other way to get the top parent Assembly/dll name? other than by ex,

Answer (score 29):

This is expected especially in the Windows Services where they are loaded by an unmanaged runtime.

Use:

```
  Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

To get unmanaged entry point file.

---

### Update

It seems you are looking for this:

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
```

Comment: Thanks Aliostad, but in this case, its a .NET Library which is used from a web application. Do you have idea how to sort out this problem?

Comment: Well, loader is IIS which is not managed. Why do you need EntryAssembly? You can use Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName to find out which unmanaged entry point it was.

Comment: @Aliostad, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName gives me the full path C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\DevelopmentServer\\9.0\\WebDev.WebServer.exe, Actually I want to get the name of the application.

Comment: What is name of the application? Do you mean web application? Your question need some work mate.

Comment: sorry @Aliostad, yes want to get the name of Web application and version.

Comment: See my update. Name of the HTTP APPLICATION is IIS specific and you cannot use ASP.NET to get that.

Comment: @Aliostad, I have solved my problem by using     Assembly.GetAssembly(ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.UnderlyingSystemType).GetName().Name I already had Exception (ex) as a parameter. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Definitely, but thats not my Answer :) it worked my using 'Assembly.GetAssembly(ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.UnderlyingSystemType).GetName().Name'

Answer (score 0):

Answering both the OP's and @Neeraj 's questions: sometimes it can also be useful to get the root of your assembly with `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` (e.g. when the Resharper test runner is making your life hard when using `GetEntryAssembly()`)

```
string rootDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string someFile = Path.Combine(
            rootDir ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
            "Foo",
            "Bar.txt");
```